# In Maple, How to divide the numbers of an array (list or vector or matrix) with the numbers of an array of equal number of rows and columns?

Tags: math, maple

In Maple, How to divide the number of data1 by the number of data2?

data1:=[1, 2, 3];

data2:=[3, 4, 5];

in order to get something like this:

data3:=[0.333, 0.5, 0.6];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In versions of Maple prior to "Maple 13" (2009) you can use the `zip` command:

```
data1 := [1, 2, 3]:

data2 := [3, 4, 5]:

zip(`/`, data1, data2);

          [1  1  3]
          [-, -, -]
          [3  2  5]
```

From Maple 13 onwards you can use the elementwise syntax,

```
data1 /~ data2;

          [1  1  3]
          [-, -, -]
          [3  2  5]
```

Notice that neither of those give you the floating-point approximations that you gave in your Question. Depending on how many digits you might want in a floating-point representation, you could use the `evalf` command:

```
T := evalf[10](data1 /~ data2):

T;

   [0.3333333333, 0.5000000000, 0.6000000000]
```

That can be further rounded to three digits,

```
evalf[3](T);

      [0.333, 0.500, 0.600]
```

You could also have only a smaller number of the (internally stored) floating-point digits be displayed.

```
interface(displayprecision=3):

T;

   [0.333, 0.500, 0.600]

# T is still stored to greater precision
lprint(T);
[.3333333333, .5000000000, .6000000000]
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation:

- [Maplesoft: Element-wise Operators](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=operators%2Felementwise)

You can use operator `/~`.

```
data3 := data1 /~ data2
```

*Disclaimer: I don't have maple on this computer to check, and I haven't used maple in many many years.*

**Bonus:** For element-wise operators in other languages, you can find a comparison list on rosettacode:

- [rosettacode: Element-wise operations](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Element-wise_operations#Maple)